# How to define a field & group by within Select Query in SQL

Tags: sql-server

At present have a column with status types, and a separate column with dates. What I would like to do is create new columns for each status type. Have created column names by using case when statements, but cannot then group by those.

At present, the table kicks out the following:

```
Reference |   Status    | Date
    ----- | ----------- | -----
        1 | Approve     | 1/1/2017
        1 | In Progress | 1/2/2017
        2 | Approve     | 1/1/2017
        2 | In Progress | 1/2/2017
        2 | Close       | 1/3/2017
```

Would like to take this and make:

```
Reference | Approve  | In Progress | Close
--------- | -------- | ----------- | -----
        1 | 1/1/2017 | 1/2/2017    | 
        2 | 1/1/2017 | 1/2/2017    | 1/3/2017
```

Have a lot of other selects, and intention is to export to excel/run automatically, so trying to avoid temp tables.

I don't know that case when is appropriate, but am struggling to find a better solution.

Comment: Read up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work based on the table you've provided (I've also handled null values to get you the output you need):-

```
select
    Reference,
    isnull(convert(varchar(10),[Approve],103),'') [Approve],
    isnull(convert(varchar(10),[In Progress],103),'') [In Progress],
    isnull(convert(varchar(10),[Close],103),'') [Close]
from
(
select 
    Reference,
    Status,
    Date 
from YourTableName
) d
pivot (min([Date]) for Status in ([Approve],[In Progress],[Close])) p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot in sql server

```
select * from #yourStatus
pivot( max(date) for [Status] in ([Approve], [In Progress],[Close])) p
```

Your table:

```
create table #yourStatus (Reference int, Status varchar(20), Date date)

insert into #yourstatus (
Reference   ,   Status  ,   Date ) values
 ( 1  ,'Approve','1/1/2017')
,( 1  ,'In Progress','1/2/2017')
,( 2  ,'Approve','1/1/2017')
,( 2  ,'In Progress','1/2/2017')
,( 2  ,'Close','1/3/2017')
```